# OpenGL 2D co-ordinate system

Tags: opengl, coordinate-systems

How does the 2D openGL co-ordinate system work?

```
glOrtho( 0.0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0);
```

creates a 2d perspective SCREEN_WIDTH wide and SCREEN_HEIGHT high

```
glTranslatef( 0.f, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0.f );
```

moves the origin(i think) to the bottom of the screen on the left.

If I wanted to create a square here what would the co-ords be?
To draw a square I would use:

```
glBegin( GL_QUADS );
    glVertex2f( ?.f, ?.f );
    glVertex2f( ?.f, ?.f );
    glVertex2f( ?.f, ?.f );
    glVertex2f( ?.f, ?.f );
glEnd();
```

what coordinates do I need to enter to draw a square at the bottom left corner(any size)

Comment: Where is your square drawing code?  If you don't do any `glTranslate`ing, you can just use the (very old and deprecated) `glVertex2f()` function and place vertexes where you *want* them to go.  I say *want* because you say "square here" and I don't know where here is.

Comment: There is no 2D OpenGL coordinate system. `glOrtho (...)` creates a projection matrix that does not produce perspective warping (orthographic, in other words). You still have a 3D coordinate system after projection, that is why there is a third set of parameters in this function. Now, when using an orthographic projection matrix, the X and Y position do not change with Z, so as long as you provide a Z coordinate in the range of [-1.0,1.0] you will have a vertex at (X,Y). Any vertex outside that Z range will be clipped. You are forgetting the viewport mapping in your question, by the way.

Comment: I am using glVertex2f() to draw the square, I want the square to be in the bottom left corner.

Comment: You are still using 3D (technically 4D) coordinates when you call that function. It just automatically sets `Z` to **0.0** and `W` to **1.0**. If you do not include ModelView transformation, and your viewport is setup with width: SCREEN_WIDTH, height: SCREEN_HEIGHT and origin: 0,0 then the point (0,0) is top-left given your projection matrix and (SCREEN_HEIGHT,SCREEN_WIDTH) is bottom-right. This should give you enough information to figure out how to draw a square at any location in your window.

Comment: @Andon M.Coleman Thanks I didn't realize that the origin was in the top left

Comment: It is not normally, but you set it that way when you called `glOrtho (...)`. The order of the parameters is: `left`, `right`, `bottom`, `top`, `zNear`, `zFar`. *Usually* in OpenGL everything is setup so that zNear < zFar and top > bottom.

Comment: By the way, if this solved your problem... feel free to write an answer yourself showing what you learned and then mark it as accepted. That is how Stack Overflow is supposed to work. I just did not feel like writing this as an answer; I figured you would learn more if you arrived at the solution on your own.